# Tests are hanging when running in Jenkins which runs as a background task

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, background-process

In my company, we execute Selenium UI tests in Jenkins which runs on a remote machine. But this Jenkins server runs as a background task. We are unable to set Jenkins to run as a foreground task since our company gave us this remote machine.

Now the problem is most of the tests are hanging without terminating the Chrome after the below (this is the last log displayed in the Jenkins console when hanging a job).
[image]

I checked these same tests in another temporary remote machine in which Jenkins runs as a foreground task, but here all these tests were successfully passed without hanging.

But we cannot use such a remote machine (in which Jenkins runs as a foreground task) since we were strictly asked to use the remote machine mentioned here first.

Please can anyone suggest a solution to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.